# A criterion for independence based on Characteristic function

Tags: probability-theory, characteristic-functions, independence

Let $X$ and $Y$ be real-valued random variables defined on the same space.  Let's use $\phi_X$ to denote the characteristic function of $X$.  If $\phi_{X+Y}=\phi_X\phi_Y$ then must $X$ and $Y$ be independent?

Comment: No, as the case $X=Y=$ standard Cauchy shows.

Comment: @Did why this is a counterexample?

Comment: @Connor Did you try to compute the characteristic function of a standard Cauchy random variable? If you did, this should be clear. If you did not, what are you asking?

Comment: I flagged [Connor's question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2054888/product-of-characteristic-functions-implies-independence/2055407#2055407) as a duplicate but ended up expanding your comment to an answer, @Did

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The property in your post is called [subindependence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subindependence), and it is strictly weaker than independence. (Note that some people use the term "subindependent" as a synonym for "uncorrelated".) In addition to the references given in Wikipedia, you can find an example in [this short note](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/tast.2009.09051#.UX7oBsp0u9s). Unfortunately it's behind a paywall. The example consists of two random variables with joint *pdf* 
$$h(x,y)=f(x)f(y)(1+\cos x\cos 3y)$$ 
where
$$f(x)=C\left(\int_0^{1/2} \exp(1/(4s^2-1))\cos (sx)\,ds\right)^2$$
with appropriate normalizing constant $C$.

Answer (score 23):

As user75064 already pointed out, the answer is "no". However, there is the following result:

> Let $X,Y$ be $\mathbb{R}^d$-valued random variables. Then the following statements are equivalent.
>
> 1. $X,Y$ are independent
> 2. $\forall \eta,\xi \in \mathbb{R}^d: \mathbb{E}e^{\imath \, (X,Y) \cdot (\xi,\eta)} = \mathbb{E}e^{\imath \, X \cdot \xi} \cdot \mathbb{E}e^{\imath \, Y \cdot \eta}$

i.e. if the characteristic function of the random vector $(X,Y)$ equals the product of the characteristic function of $X$ and $Y$, then $X$ and $Y$ are independent ([proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287138/moment-generating-functions-characteristic-functions-of-x-y-factor-implies-x/287321#287321)).

Comment: the small letter that you have in the exponent is the imaginary number $i$, right?

Comment: @CarlosMendoza Yes....