# Does $\varphi_{X+Y}(t)=\varphi_X(t)\varphi_Y(t)$ imply independence of $X$ and $Y$?

Tags: probability, characteristic-functions, independence

It shouldn't, but I am blanking on a counterexample.

ETA: Note that the $t$ is shared on both sides - which differentiates this from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287138/moment-generating-functions-characteristic-functions-of-x-y-factor-implies-x). Similarly $F_{X,Y}(x,y)=F_X(x)F_Y(y)$ implies independence, but $F_{X,Y}(t,t)=F_X(t)F_Y(t)$ doesn't.

Comment: Interesting.$  $

Comment: Could you please specify what $\varphi_{X}(t)$ denotes. Is it the characteristic function of random variable $X$?

Comment: @AndersMuszta Judging by the tag, it is.

Comment: Close vote retracted.

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/376511/a-criterion-for-independence-based-on-characteristic-function), may be helpful for people who see this question in the future. Note that the claim in the linked question is still true (the answerer to that question also responded to the related question I have here).

Answer (score 2):

$X=Y$ Cauchy is a counter-example I was looking for.

Comment: your characteristic function relation is equivalent to $f_{X+Y}(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_X(u) f_Y(x-u) du =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X,Y}(u,x-u) du $ but this doesn't imply $f_X(u) f_Y(x-u) = f_{X,Y}(u,x-u)$ almost everywhere : your are viewing $f_{X,Y}(u,x-u)$ a $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ function only by summing it on parallel lines, but to prove it is really the product of two $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ functions you would need more information on it. how many more ? that is the question.