# Additivity of cumulants of dependent random variables?

Tags: probability-distributions, independence, cumulants

What sequences of real-valued random variables $X_1,X_2,X_3,\ldots$ exist for which for all $n$ and all $k$
$$
\operatorname{cum}_k (X_1+\cdots+X_n) = \operatorname{cum}_k(X_1)+\cdots + \operatorname{cum}_k(X_n)
$$
where $\operatorname{cum}_k$ is the $k$th cumulant functional, and $X_1,X_2,X_3,\ldots$ are **not** independent?

$$ \S $$

**PS:** The most usual definitions of "cumulant" that one comes across don't make clear any motivation behind the concept, so here is one that does:  The $k$th cumulant $\operatorname{cum}_k(X)$ of (the probability distribution of) a random variable $X$ is the value of a certain polynomial in the first $k$ moments $\operatorname{E}(X^\ell),\  \ell=1,\ldots,k$. The polynomial is the unique one that is so chosen that

- $\operatorname{cum}_k$ is shift-invariant for $k\ge 2$, i.e. $\operatorname{cum}_k(X+\text{constant}) = \operatorname{cum}_k(X)$ (and for $k=1$ it is shift-equivariant, i.e. $\operatorname{cum}_k(X+\text{constant}) = \operatorname{cum}_k(X)+\text{same constant}$); and
- $\operatorname{cum}_k$ is homogeneous of degree $k$; and
- $\operatorname{cum}_k$ is "cumulative", i.e. for independent random variables $X_1,X_2,X_3,\ldots$ one as for all $n$, $\operatorname{cum}_k(X_1+\cdots+X_n) = \operatorname{cum}_k(X_1) + \cdots + \operatorname{cum}_k(X_n)$.

(For example, the $4$th cumulant is the $4$th central moment minus $3$ times the square of the second central moment.)

(I suppose this characterization doesn't really explain why $k=1$ should be an exception in the first bulleted item above, where perhaps the more usual characterizations do.)

Comment: For the record, I don't believe one should ever *define* cumulants in terms of Bell polynomials or any other polynomials for that matter. As far as I'm concerned, they should universally be introduced as follows: the mgf of the sum of independent random variables is the product of the mgf's of the factors, so sadly the higher moments are related by a polynomial mess (convolutions). However, taking the (formal) logarithm turns the product into a sum, sorting everything right out--sums go to sums. This definition for instance makes keej's reformulation of the original question obvious.

Answer (score 2):

If all of the cumulants are additive, that means the cumulant generating function is additive, meaning that $\log \textbf{E} e^{-itX_1} + \log \textbf{E} e^{-it X_2} = \log \textbf{E} e^{-it(X_1+X_2)}$.

Now your question reduces to [A criterion for independence based on Characteristic function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/376511/a-criterion-for-independence-based-on-characteristic-function), and it turns out the variables do not have to be independent.