# Verifying a Brownian motion through the Laplace transform

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

> Let $X(t)$ be a continuous stochastic process and $\mathcal G(t)$ be
>   the $\sigma$-algebra  generated by $\{X(\tau) : \tau\leq t \}$.
>   Suppose that for any $0\leq s\leq t$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb C$
>   $$\mathbb{E}\left[\exp(\lambda X(t))\, |\,  \mathcal G(s) \right] =
>  \exp\left(\frac{1}{2}|\lambda|^2(t-s) + \lambda X(s) \right). $$ Prove, that $X(t)$ is a Brownian motion.

My attempt. From the equation above it is easy to conclude, that 
for any $0\leq t_1\leq t_2$ 
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\exp(\lambda ( X(t_2) - X(t_1)) \right] =
 \exp\left(\frac{1}{2}|\lambda|^2(t_2-t_1)\right), $$
and, as the Laplace transform determines the distribution completely, 
$$
X(t_2) - X(t_1) \sim N(0, t_2-t_1).
$$

Now, my question is how to prove the independence of increments ?

Comment: Take the next step and compte $\Bbb E[\exp(\alpha X(s)+\beta(X(t)-X(s)))]$ for $0\le s\le t$.

Comment: Computing $\Bbb E[\exp(\alpha X(s)+\beta(X(t)-X(s)))] = \exp(\frac{1}{2}(\alpha^2s + \beta^2(t-s)))$. Does it imply independence, and why?

Comment: It shows $\Bbb E[\exp(\alpha X(s)+\beta(X(t)-X(s)))]=\Bbb E[\exp(\alpha X(s))]\cdot\Bbb E[\exp(\beta(X(t)-X(s)))]$ for all real (or complex, for that matter) $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: @NikitaEvseev If you don't know what to make of JohnDawkin's comment, then have a look at this answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/287321/36150

Comment: @JohnDawkins and saz thanks for your help. Below I post the solution.

Comment: Apparently, here $X(t)$ is $\mathbb R^2$ valued (random) and $\lambda X(t)$ should be understood as the inner product in $\mathbb R^2$. Otherwise, for a 1-dimensional Brownian motion you don't get $|\lambda|^2$ in the exponent of the right hand side.

Answer (score 1):

To prove that the process $X(t)$ is a Brownian motion one has to show that increments are normally distributed and are independent.

1. Here I use the fact that the Laplace transform (characteristic functions) determines the distribution of a random variable. For any $0\leq s\leq t$, $\lambda\in\mathbb C$ have $$\mathbb{E}\left[\exp(\lambda ( X(t) - X(s)) \right] =\\  \mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}\left(\exp(\lambda ( X(t) - X(s)) \,|\, \mathcal G(s)\right)\right]=\\  \mathbb{E} \left[\exp(-\lambda X(s))\mathbb{E}\left(\exp(\lambda ( X(t)) \,|\, \mathcal G(s)\right)\right] = \\
    \mathbb{E}\left[\exp(-\lambda X(s)) \exp\left(\frac{1}{2}|\lambda|^2(t-s) + \lambda X(s)\right)\right]=\\  \exp\left(\frac{1}{2}|\lambda|^2(t-s)\right).$$ Thus we conclude that  $X(t_{t})-X(t_{s}) \sim N(0, t-s)$.
2. The independence of increments follows from Kac's theorem for characteristic functions.

   > **Theorem (Kac's theorem)** The random variables $X, Y$ are independent if and only if $$\mathbb E\left[\exp(i ( \alpha X + \beta Y) \right] =\mathbb E\left[\exp(i\alpha X)\right]\cdot\mathbb E\left[\exp(i\beta Y)\right]$$ for all $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb R$.

   (The result of this kind discussed a lot on MSE: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/287321/23566), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/376511/23566).  )
   Using the same argument as in 1. obtain $$\Bbb E[\exp(i(\alpha X(s)+\beta(X(t)-X(s))))]=\\ \Bbb E[\exp(i\alpha X(s))]\cdot\Bbb E[\exp(i\beta(X(t)-X(s)))].$$
   This means that increments $X(s), X(t)-X(s)$ are independent.   In the same way one can show independence of any number of increments.