# Product of characteristic functions implies independence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, characteristic-functions

I meet a problem saying "random variables $X,Y$ are independent iff the characteristic function of $X+Y$ is equal to the product of characteristic functions of $X$ and $Y$." It is not hard to the the forward direction is true. I wonder how could we show the backward?

Comment: What is your source for the problem asking to prove that "Random variables X, Y are independent iff the characteristic function of X+Y is equal to the product of characteristic functions of X and Y"? (Note that the assertion: "If random variables X, Y are independent iff the characteristic function of X+Y is equal to the product of characteristic functions of X and Y." is absurd since one cannot write "If P iff Q".)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You cannot](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/376511/a-criterion-for-independence-based-on-characteristic-function) as it is not necessarily true. For a counter example, let $X$ be a [Cauchy random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution) and let $X = Y$ a.s. The characteristic function of the Cauchy with location $x_0$ and scale $\gamma$ is given by

$$
\phi_X(t) = e^{i x_0 t + \gamma \lvert t\rvert}
$$
and thus
$$
\phi_X(t)\phi_Y(t) = \left(e^{i x_0 t + \gamma \lvert t\rvert}\right)^2 = e^{ix_0\cdot 2t + \gamma \lvert 2t\rvert } = E[e^{it\cdot 2X}] = E[e^{it(X+Y)}] = \phi_{X+Y}(t),
$$
but $X$ and $Y$ are not independent. (Example motivated by [user @Did](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/376511/a-criterion-for-independence-based-on-characteristic-function#comment809537_376511))