# I want to show $\phi_{X}(a_{1},a_{2},\cdots,a_{n})=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\phi_{X_{i}}(a_{i})$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, characteristic-functions

Let $n \in \mathbb N$ and $X$ be an $\mathbb R^n$ valued random variable on $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,P)$ Define its characteristic function  to be $$\phi_{X}(a)=E(e^{i\langle X,a\rangle})$$
where $a \in \mathbb R^n$ and $\langle X,a\rangle(\omega)=\sum_{j=1}^{n}X_{j}(\omega)a_{j}$.

Suppose $X=(X_{1},X_{2},\cdots,X_{n})$, where each $\{X_{i}:1\le i\le n\}$ is a real valued random variable on  $(\Omega ,\mathcal B,P)$ , Then show that  $\{X_{i}:1\le i\le n\}$ are independent if and only if $$\phi_{X}(a_{1},a_{2},\cdots,a_{n})=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\phi_{X_{i}}(a_{i})$$

where $a_{i}\in \mathbb R$, for $1\le i \le n$.

thanks for help

Comment: [http://math.stackexchange.com/a/287321](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/287321/36150).