# X,Y,Z are mutually independent random variables. Is X and Y+Z independent?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> X,Y,Z are mutually independent random variables. Is X and Y+Z
>   independent?

Please, give me a hint how to prove it?

Comment: I took undegraduate course in probability, but it looks like I forgot a lot. I know basic distributions, understand linearity of expectation,  and so on.

Comment: Look into the mathematical definition of independent variables

Answer (score 3):

Based on [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287138/moment-generating-functions-characteristic-functions-of-x-y-factor-implies-x/287321#287321),

\begin{gather*}
\mathbb{E}[e^{i(X+Y,Z)\cdot(s,t)}] = \mathbb{E}[e^{is(X+Y) + tZ}] \stackrel{*}= \mathbb{E}[e^{isX}]\mathbb{E}[e^{isY}]\mathbb{E}[e^{itZ}] = \mathbb{E}[e^{is(X+Y)}]\mathbb{E}[e^{itZ}],
\end{gather*}
where $*$ follows by assumption. I have assumed the expectations are well-defined.

Edit: note that this is different from $\mathbb{E}[e^{is(X+Y+Z)}] = \mathbb{E}[e^{is(X+Y)}]\mathbb{E}[e^{isZ}]$, which does not imply independence.