# independence of a sum of random variables

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X,Y,Z$ be independent random variables. How to show that then also $X+Y$ and $Z$ are independent?

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1546247/x-y-z-mutually-independent-implies-xy-independent-of-z) is a duplicate

Comment: Think about mgfs (or characteristic functions)