# A proof of Lévy's theorem: how to obtain the independence $X_t-X_s \perp \mathcal{F}_s$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales, independence, local-martingales

I'm reading about Lévy's theorem at page $42$ of these [notes](https://ipgold.epfl.ch/%7Eleveque/Lecture_Notes/sc2_final.pdf), i.e.,

---

> Let $X$ be a continuous local martingale such that $X_0=0$ a.s. and $\langle X\rangle_t=t$ a.s., $\forall t \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$. Then $X$ is a standard Brownian motion.

**Proof.** $\forall c \in \mathbb{R}, c X$ is a continuous local martingale such that $\langle c X\rangle_t=c^2 t$. Therefore, by Theorem 7.10, the process $\left(Y_t=\exp \left(c X_t-\frac{c^2 t}{2}\right), t \in \mathbb{R}_{+}\right)$is a martingale, i.e.,
$$
\mathbb{E}\left(\exp \left(c X_t-\frac{c^2 t}{2}\right) \mid \mathcal{F}_s\right)=\exp \left(c X_s-\frac{c^2 s}{2}\right), \quad \forall c \in \mathbb{R}
$$
or
$$
\mathbb{E}\left(\exp \left(c\left(X_t-X_s\right)\right) \mid \mathcal{F}_s\right)=\exp \left(\frac{c^2(t-s)}{2}\right), \quad \forall c \in \mathbb{R} . \quad (\star)
$$

**Fact 1:** since the right-hand side is deterministic, $X_t-X_s \perp \mathcal{F}_s$. Moreover, by taking expectations, we obtain
$$
\mathbb{E}\left(\exp \left(c\left(X_t-X_s\right)\right)\right)=\exp \left(\frac{c^2(t-s)}{2}\right), \quad \forall c \in \mathbb{R} .
$$

**Fact 2:** this implies that $X_t-X_s \sim \mathcal{N}(0, t-s)$. Therefore, $X$ is a standard Brownian motion.

---

**My question** Could you please elaborate on the proof of **Fact 1**, i.e., how $(\star)$ implies $X_t-X_s$ is independent of $\mathcal F_s$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find another proof of Lévy's characterisation in [Schilling, Partszch, Boettcher](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9783110307306/pdf); 9.12 p. 148; the use of characteristic functions is less troublesome, in my opinion, than MGFs. In the reference, we get $E[e^{i\xi (X_t-X_s)}|\mathscr{F}_s]=e^{-(t-s)\xi^2/2}$; then multiplying by $\mathbf{1}_F$ for any $\mathscr{F}_s$-measurable set $F$ and then taking expectations we obtain the relation
$$E[e^{i\xi (X_t-X_s)}\mathbf{1}_F]=E[e^{i\xi (X_t-X_s)}]P(F),\forall F \in \mathscr{F}_s$$
which the authors then claim to be sufficient for $X_t-X_s$ to be independent from $\mathscr{F}_s$. This, however, is not really immediate. We may also choose any rv $Z$ s.t. $\sigma(Z)\subseteq \mathscr{F}_s$; in this case we obtain
$$E[e^{i\xi_1 (X_t-X_s)}e^{i\xi_2 Z}]=E[e^{i\xi_1 (X_t-X_s)}]E[e^{i\xi_2 Z}],\forall \xi_1,\xi_2\in \mathbb{R}$$
This actually proves independence of $X_t-X_s$ and $Z$ for any such $Z$ $\mathscr{F}_s$-measurable due to an important, but elusive theorem known as [Kac's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287138/moment-generating-functions-characteristic-functions-of-x-y-factor-implies-x). At this point choose the $\mathscr{F}_s$-measurable function $\mathbf{1}_F$ for some arbitrary $F \in \mathscr{F}_s$, we get for any Borel $B$
$$\begin{aligned}P(\{X_t-X_s\in B\}\cap F)&=P(X_t-X_s\in B,\mathbf{1}_F=1)=\\
&=P(X_t-X_s\in B)P(\mathbf{1}_F=1)=\\
&=P(X_t-X_s\in B)P(F)
\end{aligned}$$
But this proves independence of $\sigma(X_t-X_s)$ and $\mathscr{F}_s$, since this holds for all $F\in \mathscr{F}_s$.