# Pointwise convergent random variables preserves independence with respect to a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, independence

Let $\{X_n\}$ be a sequence of random variables. $X_n\rightarrow X$ a.s. Let $G$ be a $\sigma$-algebra. Suppose each $X_n$ is independent of $G$. Is it true that $X$ is also independent of $G$?

I proved it in this way:

**Fact 1** a random variable $X$ is independent of a $\sigma$-algebra $G$ if and only if $\forall A\in G$, $X$ is independent of $1_A$.

**Fact 2** [Kac's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287138/moment-generating-functions-characteristic-functions-of-x-y-factor-implies-x/287321#287321): two random variables $X,Y$ are independent if and only if
$\forall \eta,\xi \in \mathbb{R}^d: \mathbb{E}e^{i (X,Y) \cdot (\xi,\eta)} = \mathbb{E}e^{i  X \cdot \xi} \cdot \mathbb{E}e^{i  Y \cdot \eta}$

By the two facts above, we can let $X=X_n$ and $Y=1_A$ and use dominant convergence theorem to finish the proof.

So my question is:

1. Can somebody help verify the proof or provide some suggestions?
2. Is there any alternative approach instead of using Kac's theorem(Which I failed to find this theorem on Google)? Thank you very much.